# Find a 3D linear transformation matrix when 2 points are known, assuming only rotations around origin axes?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the 3D linear transformation matrix based on known points. I also know that the transformation involves only rotations around axes through the origin.

So far I though about following approach, given 3 points p,q and r and their transformations p', q' and r':

```
p' = A.p
q' = A.q
r' = A.r
```

A is a 3x3 matrix. If I make up two other 3x3 matrices

`O = [p q r] and O' = [p' q' r']`

I can write the above as

`O' = A.O`

So the solution is

`A = O'.O^-1`

I hope that is correct?

But since I know that the transformation only involves rotations, would this allow me to solve the problem with only 2 known points?

The goal is to implement this in Python; implementing the above should be rather straightforward in numpy, I suppose...

Best regards,
Vic

Answer (score 0):

given two pairs `(p, p')` and `(q, q')` you could calculate `r = cross(p, q)`, and `r' = cross(p', q')` then you have three points and you can apply your solution for three points.

Here an example code

```py
# just generate a random rotation matrix
Q_hidden, _ = np.linalg.qr(np.random.randn(3, 3))
# two points
p1, q1 = np.random.randn(2, 3)
# their rotated counterpart
p2, q2 = Q_hidden @ p1, Q_hidden @ q1
# create the third point
r1 = np.cross(p1, q1)
r2 = np.cross(p2, q2)
# find the rotation matrix
Q_found = np.linalg.solve([p1, q1, r1], [p2, q2, r2]).T
# sanity check
assert np.allclose(Q_hidden, Q_found)
```